# Is it thread safe to instantiate inner class with a final outer class object?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, instantiation, inner-classes

I read the tutorial about inner class on oracle.com:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

The tutorial contains simple examples:

```
class OuterClass {
    ...
    class InnerClass {
        ...
    }
}
```

Instantiation like this:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

My question is if I have a final instance of the outer class:

```
public class OuterClass {
    private static final OuterClass outerObject = new OuterClass();
    class InnerClass{
        //... some fields, methods here
    }
    public static void functn(){
        InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
        //... use the inner object...
    }
}
```

Then can I safely do the instantiation in 2 threads concurrently? (Calling `functn()` in 2 threads)

Comment: Your question is unclear (for example that line could be a local variable which by definition is thread safe) - can you show a complete example?

Comment: It depends what is in the "..."'s

Comment: @assylias  example added.

Comment: @StephenC If inner class only contains some fields, plain getters and setters, and the static method simply set some value in the inner object, then there is no problem at all, right?

Comment: @Griddoor - are the fields initialized?  Is there a constructor?

Comment: @StephenC No constructor defined. Fields are not initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it thread safe to instantiate inner class with a final outer class object?

In general, it depends on the context.  This is true in your example too.

The thread-safety of the instantiation performed in `functn` depends on whether the constructor (not shown) and other initialization (not shown) for `InnerClass` is thread-safe, and (indirectly) whether the `OuterClass` instantiation was thread-safe.

The one thing we can say for sure is that there is a "happens before" between `outerObject = new OuterClass()` and `outerObject.new InnerClass()`.  However, that is not sufficient for a blanket assurance that it is all thread-safe.

---

As a rule, it is only meaningful to talk about the thread-safety of code that is complete and executable.  When you have ellipsis, you have to consider all of the *possible* code that *might* go in there ... including stuff that might be non-thread-safe.  The reasoning becomes difficult.

Comment: I think I understand now. Of course I shouldn't do instantiation concurrently when constructor contains dangerous code which is not thread safe.